# jquery toggle() issue inside cloned content

Tags: jquery, clone, togglebutton

I have an class that is being cloned so multiple inputs can be done.  Inside of this is an issues area that has hidden content that I want to display onclick of the yes button.  Currently this toggle isn't working.  I'm assuming it has something to do with being inside the cloned class, but I don't know enough to understand why.
Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/484u32qn/6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".issuesshow").click(function() {
  $(".plantarea").toggle();
  });

  $(".ft1issues").click(function() {
  $(".ft1area").toggle();
  });

  $(".ft2issues").click(function() {
  $(".ft2area").toggle();
  });

  $('.button-add').click(function() {
  //we select the box clone it and insert it after the box
  $('.box.assembly').clone().show().removeClass("assembly").insertAfter(".box:last");
  }).trigger("click");

  $(document).on("click", ".button-remove", function() {
  $(this).closest(".box").remove();
  });

});
```

Comment: in JSFiddle you are missing jQuery library, did you added jQuery on your website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because when you register the event handlers, the row is not yet added.

Change the order and it will work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button-add').click(function() {
    //we select the box clone it and insert it after the box
    $('.box.assembly').clone().show().removeClass("assembly").insertAfter(".box:last");
   }).trigger("click");

   $(".issuesshow").click(function() {
        $(".plantarea").toggle();
   });

   $(".ft1issues").click(function() {
       $(".ft1area").toggle();
   });

   $(".ft2issues").click(function() {
       $(".ft2area").toggle();
   });

   $(document).on("click", ".button-remove", function() {
       $(this).closest(".box").remove();
   });

});
```

Note: [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) as such will not copy event handlers

Comment: What can I use that will copy the event handlers?

Comment: @Greek Usually I register event handlers after cloning. But try `clone(true)` - it copies event handlers too. Check clone documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

use the following syntax to dynamically change

```
  $(document).on('click', '.issuesshow', function(){
            $(this).closest('.prodchild').find('.plantarea').toggle();
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/484u32qn/13/